# How to Click loop and click on all xpath with attribute and print in console get text?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

There is a page with 12 link. I need to click on all 12 link. 
then then the a other name column which I need to print all name once click in loop.

SOLVED

List editicons1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//i[@class='material-icons']"));
        for (int j = 1; j <= editicons1.size(); j++) {
            editicons1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//i[@class='material-icons']"));
            String porfolioName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//mat-table//mat-row)[" + j + "]//mat-cell[2]"))
                    .getText();
            WebElement editicon = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//i[@class='material-icons'])[" + j + "]"));
            click1(driver, editicon, porfolioName + " portfolio edit icon");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            waitForElementPresent(driver, 30, buildportfolioheader);
            Reporter.log("Successfully rendered to Portfolio  Screen for Portfolio " + porfolioName);

Comment: Could you please provide more detail. As of current state of question it is not in state that can be answered.

Comment: Seems like a homework question. Did you try to compile the code block?